# How to find the average rate of a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I have these two problems. 
For the first one I know that

$f(x) = 50000+25x$ If I wanted to find the average cost, how would I do that? I'm confused about the equation I would need to set up.

For the second question, I was thinking that the average is just the average of 62 and 68, is this correct?

Comment: For your first question, do you know the definition of average cost?  For the second question, no that's not right.  You spend more time traveling at the slower speed.  Again, what is the definition of average speed?

Comment: no can you please explain what the definition of average cost is?

Comment: Thomas Fjærvik's answer explains it very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about it this way. The average cost is the total cost of the calculators divided by the number of calculators. Total cost is $50000 + 25x$ and number of calculators is $x$. Setting this average equal to $35$ gives you the equation given by mfl

Comment: ohh! that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**First question**

You have to solve $50000+25x=35x.$

**Second question**

$s=62\cdot t_1$ and $s=68 \cdot t_2.$ Now, $v=\frac{2s}{t_1+t_2}.$

Comment: can you please explain why i have to use that formula for the second equation?

Comment: $s$ represents the distance covered. One way it is covered by driving at $62$ mph in $t_1$ hours, the other way by driving at $68$ mph for $t_2$ hours. The average velocity is given by the total distance traveled divided by the total time spent driving.

Comment: how can s be equal to two different things? when I pluf it into the formula for velocity, which s do i use?

Comment: should I get 64.9? I solved for $t_1$ and $t_2$ and then plugged into the formula and got $\frac{2s}{s/62+s/68}$ and after simplifying i got $4216/65$

Comment: Yes. I get $v=64,86$ $\mathrm{mph}.$ It is just the harmonic mean of $62$ and $68$.